# Given million number in a list. How to mutiply each element by a constant with minimum time complexity

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I have written a java program, Which mutiply the each number in a list by some constants. Below is the program. I have created a myNewNumbers list to store those mutiplied numbers. Below are my doubts

Is there a better way to write this in minimum time complexity?
Currently In my for loop there are 10 elements. How to handle if user wants do it for 1 million elements?
I am beginner to muti threading. How do I make sure that it works in mutithreading

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MultiplyHugeNumber {

    static List<Integer> mynumbers;
    static List<Integer> myNewnumbers;
    static Integer MUTIPLY_ELEMENT=2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mynumbers= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            mynumbers.add(i);
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mynumbers.toArray()));
        myNewnumbers= new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer mynumber : mynumbers) {
            myNewnumbers.add(mynumber*MUTIPLY_ELEMENT);

        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myNewnumbers.toArray()));
    }

 o/p:[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Comment: Oh, look, premature optimizations. We live in 2016, not 1980, your computer can handle couple millions of multiplications.

Comment: Multi-Threading has nothing to do with time complexity. Either using multiple Threads or not, you have to process all the elements once, so your time complexity would be of `O(n)`. May be you are mixing it with parallel processing to reduce the total time of execution.

Answer (score 3):

(credits to @STaefi) Multiplying a list of input values by a constant value has a time complexity of `O(n)`. This complexity is not related to a multi-threaded implementation.

Your program: multiply a list of numbers by a constant falls into the category of so called ["Embarrassingly Parallel"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) problems:

> "[...] one where little or no effort is needed to separate the problem into a number of parallel tasks [...]"

Each item in your input list can be multiplied with the constant without regarding any other input item or global state.

There are various ways to parallelize the given task. Be aware that the overhead for setting the threads up might not be worth it for a small number of input values or at all in this particular example.

Example using Java 8 streams:

```
 mynumbers.parallelStream()
          .map(in -> in * MUTIPLY_ELEMENT)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a million elements, and you need to multiply each by a constant, then you're going to need to perform a million operations. There's no way around it -- it's O(n).

That said, *creating* the list can be O(1) (constant time), if you're okay with a lazily-evaluated list. Guava's [`Lists.transform`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) does just that:

```
List<Integer> myNumbers = ...
List<Integer> myNewNumbers = Lists.transform(myNumbers, i -> i * MULTIPLY_ELEMENT);
```

This doesn't reduce the overall time it takes to do all the multiplications; in fact, it'll probably take a bit *more* time overall, since it's harder for the JVM to optimize. It'll also be slower if you access the same element multiple times, since the transformation will be applied each time you do. That said, it's unlikely that it'll be slower by an amount you'll notice.

This approach also carries the limitation that you can't add new elements to the transformed list (as explained in the JavaDocs). But, depending on your scenario, there may be other benefits to getting that initial list created quickly.

Answer (score 1):

This is 100% a premature optimization, there's very likely no optimizations worth making in this case.

HOWEVER..purely "academically speaking" you would need to ask yourself a question here, namely, does it matter what order the results are in?

if not, then with Streams, this is simple, here's an example with 100 numbers:

```
    Integer MUTIPLY_ELEMENT = 2;
    List<Integer> resultNumbers = IntStream.range(0,100)
            .parallel()
            .map(i->i*MUTIPLY_ELEMENT)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

if you do care about ordering, but still want to gain the benefit of parallel processing, you can take advantage of the fact that your operation (multiplying by 2) is simple enough that the resulting numbers will still be in the same relative "natural" order and just call `sorted()` on the stream after the `map()` call. However, the sorting operation could very well take just as long as if you just did it single threaded.

Also, understand that this is by NO MEANS a "real world" scenario, you will almost never come across an actual problem like this. Hopefully you're just trying to get your head around parallelism in general, because you'd never actually want to do this type of optimization until you have tried a single-threaded model and it proves insufficient.